Game identification from scene: two soldiers forget that they're enemies while in a dungeon
I'm looking for an old fantasy computer RPG that I played in the 90s and only remember from a particular dungeon. The party is trapped in a magical labyrinth (could be a psychic prison), where they meet two soldiers from two armies that are mortal enemies in the game world. Due to the magic of the labyrinth, these soldiers are unaware that they should be enemies, and are working together to escape. As they near the exit, they have become fast friends with each other and the party. As soon as the party escapes the labyrinth with the soldiers, both of them immediately forget their new bond and see only a member of the enemy army, and attack each other without a chance to reconcile them.
I thought this could have been in Dark Sun 2, but I played a big chunk of it recently and recognize it so little that wonder if I misremember playing it in the 90s in the first place. I played (and didn't finish) a lot of these pixelly top-down crpgs back then; this scene would also fit in Baldur's Gate or Planescape: Torment, but I replayed both more recently and didn't find it there. Dark Sun 1 wasn't it either (or maybe the scene is optional and well hidden).
